# how to select multiple checkbox in automation anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

I am running a loop where if condition met to select check box. I am unable to to do select multiple check boxes. It select first check box then run loop again but doesn't select next check boxes where condition are met.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4YtC.png)

Comment: We need to see your logic (code) in order to help.  Please try to follow the question guidelines: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow+how+to+ask&t=ffsb&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

To give some insight into what you're probably experiencing - Automation Anywhere object cloning basically operates like Javascript's [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) in that it locks onto the first available item that meets the criteria you set forth in the object cloning parameters. There is no way to populate an array with these items like Javascript's [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) might do.

This is interesting because if there are multiple items on the page that you're trying to work with and object cloning, by default, sets parameters that those items share, you'll only ever be able to interact with the first one.

I would suggest looking into additional parameters that distinguish each check box using Chrome's inspector or the other properties object cloning makes available to select.